# Getting alter box message when clicking on select2 dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have added a simple select2 plugin for drop down but when i am clicking on it it is generating an alert box and saying "localhost:8080 says 1".
It is too irritating as it is creating an obstacle for the click event.
If you ever faced anything like that and solved the issue please help me out.
Thank you

html code -

```
<select class="form-control collections-select2" id="categoryNameInput">
                            <option></option>
                                <c:if test='${not empty categoryName}'>
                                    <option selected>${categoryName}</option>
                                </c:if>
                            </select>
```

Comment: Can you please post some code?

Comment: please share your code that you have tried so far

Comment: @AhmedAli  i have added the html part.Thank you

Comment: Are you using `angular`?

Comment: no just normal jquery and select2 plugin @AhmedAli

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a way to disable the alert that was happening on the click event.
I simply disable the alert from that page.

```
window.alert = function() {};
```